# How do I pause a timer in Clipchamp?

Tags: video, clipchamp

I'm editing a video in Clipchamp and am using the Countdown Timer text effect with Count Up enabled to create an on-screen timer. I want to pause the timer when it finishes so I can display the final time in the video.

How do I pause a timer in Clipchamp?

[image: Timer in clipchamp]

Comment: Did you ever figur this out?